# Caddy Server error: "Caddyfile:12 - Error during parsing: Unknown directive 'CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY'"

Tags: cloudflare, caddy, caddyfile

New to using `Caddy` server and fighting with the `Caddyfile`...

[This](https://pastebin.com/J3Ud2qvP) is the current Caddyfile that I have; when I type "`caddy`" from the command line, from within the same folder, I get the following error:

```
Caddyfile:12 - Error during parsing: Unknown directive 'CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY'
```

When I look at the docs [here](https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https#dns-challenge) the variable on the page seems to show that I have the syntax correct? *confused*

**Note:** I *do* have the `tls.dns.Cloudflare` Caddy plugin installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those docs refer to *environment variables* which are not set in the Caddyfile, they're set externally with your OS, usually through your shell: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-unix/

Comment: Aha! For some reason I was just assuming adding it to the `Caddyfile` was kind of like doing a `set` in a .bat file.Thanks!